# Access value Outside While loop

Tags: java, string, file

I am reading an entire file and I want to use the line if it contains a specific string. I am unable to use the string because it is printing `null` outside the while loop, despite the fact that I have initialized it outside the loop.

```
FileInputStream wf = new FileInputStream(pr.getSplitDir() + listfiles[i]);
BufferedReader wbf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(wf));
String wfl = "";
while ((wfl = wbf.readLine()) != null) {
    if (wfl.contains("A/C NO:")){
        // System.out.println(wfl); // Here it is Printing the correct line
    }
}
System.out.println(wfl); // Here it is printing null
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below, You have to use another String or StringBuilder to get final out put

```
     FileInputStream wf = new FileInputStream(pr.getSplitDir() + listfiles[i]);
        BufferedReader wbf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(wf));
        String wfl = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((wfl = wbf.readLine()) != null) {
            if(wfl.contains("A/C NO:")){
                //System.out.println(wfl);//Here it is Printing the correct line
                sb.append(wfl);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());//Here it is printing null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 while ((wfl = wbf.readLine()) != null) {
                if(wfl.contains("A/C NO:")){
                    //System.out.println(wfl);//Here it is Printing the correct line

                }
            }
```

Your **while loop will exit only when `wfl is null`**. So you have your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because your wbf.readLine when read null ,it assigns it wfl too and then compares to null

```
while ((wfl = wbf.readLine()) != null) {  // here wbf.readLine when read null assigns to wfl
  if(wfl.contains("A/C NO:")){
        //System.out.println(wfl);//Here it is Printing the correct line
     }
 }
```

Do it like this,if you want to print outside while loop,

```
String test ="";
String wfl ="";
while ((wfl = wbf.readLine()) != null) {
      if(wfl.contains("A/C NO:")){
            //System.out.println(wfl);//Here it is Printing the correct line
      }

      test = test + wfl ; // for assigning all line
      //test = wfl // for assigning last line
}



 System.out.println(test); // it wil print the correct line
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop, your loop need `wfl` to be `null`, so when your loop has just stopped, `wfl` is obviously `null`.